# executing an inner function depending on values determined within an outer function

Tags: r, rlang

We're trying to all users to write a function that will execute depending on variables that will be available at runtime (this is a simulation context).

The user "declares" an inner function using the "function declarer".  Later, when the outer function is called, the required piece of information (my var) is available. But we just don't know how to give it to the declared variable.

If possible, we'd like to solve this using rlang / tidyverse style tools.  Thanks in advance.

```
library(rlang)

function_declarer <- function(expr) {
  function() {
    eval(expr)
  }
}

inner_function <- function_declarer(mean(my_var))

outer_function <- function(step) {
  my_var <- c(5, 6, 7)
  # environment(step) <- env_clone(environment(step), parent = current_env()) # know this does not work
  step()
}

outer_function(inner_function)
```

Comment: This whole setup seems needlessly complex. What is wrong with just passing the `mean` function to the outer function, `run`, and the variable to the function: `run <- function(fun, my_var = 5:7) fun(my_var); run(mean)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you just can grab the unevaluated expression and then evaluate it later with `eval` and the local environment.

```
library(rlang)

function_declarer <- function(expr) {
  enexpr(expr)
}

inner_function <- function_declarer(mean(my_var))

outer_function <- function(step) {
  my_var <- c(5, 6, 7)
  eval(step)
}

outer_function(inner_function)
```

So in this scenario we're working with expressions rather than functions. Functions would add a complication because variables are lexically scoped so free variables are looked for in the environment where the function is defined, not where it is called. Using expressions avoids this problem. So you could simplify this with just

```
inner_function <- quote(mean(my_var))        # base
inner_function <- rlang::expr(mean(my_var))  # rlang
```

Comment: Nice solution to the question as asked, and well worth an upvote, though I have to admit I find this whole set-up a bit odd. What's wrong with writing a function that takes `my_var` as an argument? Is there some subtle use case I'm missing that would necessitate this complexity? (Perhaps this would be better asked of the OP than yourself)

Comment: @AllanCameron. I agree that writing a function may be a more sound way to handle the problem. I guess it avoids the overhead of having to have a particular matching function signature but you still somehow have to know about all the "magic" variable names. I think it's a tidyverse inspired thing where everyone want to write functions with having to type "function" and pass column names as unquoted symbols. I guess it's a style thing.